# Form logado deslogado no recarga bien la página

Tags: php

llevo tiempo siguiendo esta página para hasta hoy no me he visto obligado a preguntar, pero estoy ya desesperado, la cuestión es que estoy realizando una página en php y ahora voy por la parte de logado y deslogado y el problema es que tengo dos form, uno para logar y otro para deslogar, cuando hago la consulta recargo la página y me oculta el de logado para mostrar el de deslogado y viceversa. El problema viene que al recargar la página para que oculte y desoculte tengo que hacerlo dos veces, ya que la primera recarga pero no funciona, os lo explico con el código:

```
<?php
if ( empty($_SESSION['loggedin']) ) {
    echo "<span class='heading'>";
        echo "<br><h6>Logarse</h6><hr />";
        echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"post\" >";
            echo "<label>Usuario:</label><br>";
            echo "<input style= \"width: 7em; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px;\" name=\"username\" type=\"text\" id=\"username\" required>";
            echo "<br><br>";
            echo "<label>Contraseña:</label><br>";
            echo "<input style= \"width: 7em; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px;\" name=\"password\" type=\"password\" id=\"password\" required>";
            echo "<br><br>";
            echo "<input style=\"text-align: center;\"type=\"submit\" name=\"Submit\" value=\"LOGIN\">";
        echo "</form>";
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        inicia_sesion($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
        //header('Location: index.php');
    }
} else {
            echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"post\" >";
            echo "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"" . $_SESSION['username'] . "\" name=\"usuario\">";
            echo "<input style=\"text-align: center;\"type=\"submit\" name=\"Submit\" value=\"LOGOUT\">";
            echo "</form>";
            if(isset($_POST['usuario'])){
                unset ($_SESSION['loggedin']);
                session_destroy();
                header("Location: index.php");
            }
}?>
```

El if muestra un form u otro según la variable $_SESSION['loggedin'], para el logado uso la función:

```
function inicia_sesion ($username, $password){
ob_start();
$host_db = "localhost";
$user_db = "******";
$pass_db = "********";
$db_name = "Juegario";
$tbl_name = "Usuarios";
$conexion = new mysqli($host_db, $user_db, $pass_db, $db_name);

if ($conexion->connect_error) {
 die("La conexion falló: " . $conexion->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE nombre_usuario = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query( $conexion, $sql ) or die ( "Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {

        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['start'] = time();
        $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (1 * 60);

        echo "Bienvenido! " . $_SESSION['username'];
    } else {
        echo "Username o Password estan incorrectos.";
        //echo "<p> error</p>"; 
    }
mysqli_close($conexion);

header("location:index.php");
ob_end_flush();
}}
```

Cuando llamo header("location:index.php"); se recarga la página pero me sigue mostrando el form de logado, si le vuelvo a dar entonces ya desaparece y aparece el de deslogado y viceversa ¿alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esta parte:

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    inicia_sesion($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
```

Debería ir al principio, antes de:

```
if ( empty($_SESSION['loggedin']) ) {
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Javi, efectivamente era eso, que despiste, me pasaba lo mismo con el logaut por lo que tambien tuve que sacar el ese if, ahora todo perfecto, gracias de nuevo.